# Master branch sometimes ahead of developing branch

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I am using GIT and GITLAB (current versions). The master branch is protected against pushing. I work on a developing branch and request to merge this branch into master from time to time. CI compiles and runs unit tests, the branch is then merged if everything succeeds. Usually I use fast forward merges.

From time to time my master is ahead of the developing branch although there is nobody else committing and there are no other branches. GITLAB then refuses to merge. If I fetch/pull master and develop locally, I can merge develop into master without any problems.

I don't understand how my master can be ahead of develop as I only merge develop into master (fast forward). Even without fast fowrard the Master would be ahead by commits but without changes, GITLAB wouldn't refuse to merge. I see a lot of differences that are already present in master but the compare branch function states they are not in master.

I already created a new repo from scratch, updates gitlab but after some merges the master suddelny is ahead again.

I am also working on an other project using the same strategy (develop/master) on the same gitlab/git instances but without merge CI (only deploy after merge). There these problems do not appear.

Comment: Are they merge commits? Who's the author? Did I get correctly that you're working alone on the repo?

Comment: As I use fast forward there are no merge commits. Yes, I am working alone on the repo. I never had that before. The most strange thing is that comparing develop to master shows differences that are already in master if I look at the files. I am now checking the disks of my Gitlab server...

Comment: I wondered too. Could it be that they expected some sort of log for example, or something more specific to examine? Just speculating. (I also note there's a close vote for "Needs details or clarity".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for diverging was squashing the commits on merge to master. If I omit squashing the commits the branches no longer diverge. In the future I will only squash commit on merge if I delete the source branch too.